# Shape From Focus datasets or benchmarks

Tags: computer-vision, focus, shapes, opencv3.0

I would like to find some dataset/benchmark for my student research about shape from focus. But I haven't found something that is suitable for me.
I need sequence of images with different and defined focal length of camera in every picture.
Please help me.
I would like to get depth map of scene and I need data for testing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is extremely vague and shows little in the way of research effort. Would you kindly further clarify your intent and/or show an example of what you have tried thus far?

Comment: If fixed focus will also do: contact www.alicona.com, explain them what you want to do and kindly ask for assistance. I'm sure they'll help you out with some data. I used to work there and they pile up terrabytes of image stacks of well known optical systems. Unless you work for their competitors it's worth a try :)

Answer (score 0):

today little datasets is dedicated for this. an
https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~nianyi/LFSD.htm is one example. other way is use datasets with depth map of other tecnics like http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/scenes2001/data/venus/, who it is made for stereo vision, however can be used for that, As long as you know how to use iris filter.